# How to populate modal window by entity from controller in thymeleaf by ajax query

Tags: ajax, spring, modal-dialog, thymeleaf, materialize

I want to show a particular user with the help of a materialized modal window by clicking on 'view' button. I'm trying to do this by ajax query to my controller. Also I have an error: 
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "user.firstName" (users:190)

Table:

```
<tr th:each="user : ${users}">
            <td th:text="${user.firstName}"></td>
            <td th:text="${user.lastName}"></td>
            <td th:text="${user.username}"></td>
            <td>
                <a th:onclick="'javascript:viewUser(\'' + ${user.id} +'\');'" class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light yellow"><i class="material-icons">visibility</i></a>
                <a href="#updateUser" class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light blue btn modal-trigger"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
                <a th:href="${'/users/delete/' + user.id}" class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light red"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Modal:

```
   <div id="viewUser" class="modal modal-fixed-footer" th:fragment="view">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h4>View User</h4>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <table>
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>First Name: </td>
                                    <td th:text="${user.firstName}"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Last Name: </td>
                                    <td th:text="${user.lastName}"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Username</td>
                                    <td th:text="${user.username}"></td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-light btn-floating red"><i class="material-icons">close</i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS function:

```
function viewUser(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/users/view/" + id,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $('#viewUserHolder').html(response);
            $('#viewUser').modal('open');
        }
    });
}
```

Method in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/view/{id}")
public String view(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, ModelMap modelMap) {
    User user = userRepository.findOne(id);
    modelMap.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "users :: view";
}
```

Comment: Update the question and post full stacktrace. The problem somewhere in your code. It tries to get firstName of the user but there is something wrong. Could be user is null or does not have getFirstName() method or something fails in the method.

Comment: I managed to cope with this error. I get right data in the console, but my modal window is empty by some reason. Could you help me to find a solution for this? I updated code, please check it. I'm trying to use this tutorial  https://qtzar.com/2017/03/24/ajax-and-thymeleaf-for-modal-dialogs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by adding $('#viewUser).modal(). Modal window didn't want to open.

```
function viewUser(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/users/view/" + id,
            success: function(response) {
                $('#viewUserHolder').html(response);
                $('#viewUser').modal();
                $('#viewUser').modal('open');
            }
        });
    }
```